# How can I make this dropdown always show beyond the parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a very specific HTML/CSS and/or JS question. I have created an example at [this fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0xu16rc5/) to show the problem.

I have a scrollable div which is parent to a table:

```
<div style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 300px;">
  <table style="width: 100%;">
```

...and one of my table rows contains a button with a drop-down menu:

```
<td>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
```

My problem is that when you click the button to open the drop-down menu, it is opened within the scrollable area, so if you don't scroll down you won't see the drop-down menu. But, I would like the button to open this dropdown outside of the scrollable area. Is there any way to do that, such that the drop down is visible, while letting the UI still be scalable (meaning, if I resize my window, it should still show the drop-down menu under the button)? Furthermore, I have a requirement to keep the scrollable area as it is, meaning, the scrollable area needs to be there for when there is too much content (this is a design requirement).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is way to make your child container `ul.dropdown-menu` "ignore" the `overflow: hidden` of its parent... If you need to keep the HTML structure as is, I think the only option would be to remove `position: relative` from `.dropdown` and set the absolute top and left position of `.dropdown-menu` with JavaScript on button click (f.e. using button's position).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the drop down inside the table? Why not use it outside the table? If you insist on using it inside the table, at least keep it on the first table-row or in the table header...

Updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xu16rc5/1/)

```
<div style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 300px;">
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: left">Column 1</th>
        <th style="text-align: left">Column 2</th>
        <th style="text-align: left">Column 3</th>
        <th>          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
              Dropdown
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
              <li><a href="#">Action A</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Action B</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Action C</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this is not a good solution to my problem because the drop-down is on all rows in the actual product, for obvious reasons of aligning content and making the UI scale with ease, but in my fiddle I only included one of them.

Comment: Just wanted to see if there is a reason why you are it using a select tag? This would be the best way to solve your issue.